# How to ensure the relative positioning of responsive images?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, responsiveness

I am working on building a website and below is my desired outcome.

**Desired:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/JI7tQ.png
Note: there is an image on the left making it 5 images in total.

However when I resize the broswer the grid-images stack together like so..

**Actual:**  https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNSLP.png

Below is my code

**HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>RM</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"
    <meta name= "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" >


</head>
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="port">
                <div id="vertical-title" class="column-1">
                  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/60x650" >
                </div>

                    <div class="row-1">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/550x325" class="img-responsive">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/550x325" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>

                    <div class="row-1">
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/550x325" class="img-responsive" >
                        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/550x325" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>



</body>
<footer>
</footer>
</html>
</html>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
img#vertical-title {
    border : 8px;
    border-color : red;
    width : 10%;
}


div#vertical-title{
    display: block;
        float: left;
        margin-left:0%;
}

img.img-responsive  {
  display: inline;
  max-width: 75%;
  height: auto;
}


.column-1 {

    display: inline;
    max-width:5%;
}

.row-1 .container{
    display : inline;
    max-width: 95%;

}
img.row-1{

    display:inline;
    max-width:100%;
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {


div.test h1{
    color:blue;
}
img#vertical-title {
    border : 8px;
    border-color : red;
    width : 10%;
}

img.inline-div {
    width : 25%;
}

}
```

**Desired Behavior**

I would like for the four images to keep their position relative to each other and shrink as the window gets smaller. In other words, I want the 2x2 grid to reduce in size and not become a 4*1 grid.

Also I would like the left most image to have the height equal to the height of the screen.

**Note** The images are responsive when they are stacked together.

**Questions**

What is the best way to achieve this behavior ? 
My gut is screaming JavaScript.

Comment: you can attain the results using pure css. i believe you can do it by changing the `max-width` property in `img.img-responsive` to be `49%`

Comment: Hi thanks and yes, that achieved the effect I was looking for but not for all screen sizes. If the screen gets small enough (Iphone 5) the images again begin to stack.

Comment: remove whitespaces between the img tags by putting the tags on the same line, it's solved a few problems for me.

Comment: @RichardMpanga What is the use of the image inside **column-1** class?

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J.This image is going to be a vertical banner. I have not created it yet thats why there is a placehodler

Comment: @RichardMpanga Ok, what is the size of the banner or its expected width?

Comment: @iam-decoder Thank you! Last thing I would have thought is white space

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J.it's expected width is 60px or 5% of the width of the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **cleaned up** your code with more **reusable** and **responsive** one.

**Here's the [JsFiddle demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/8Ln4ypqx/1/).**

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>Welcome</h3>
    <div class="port">
        <div id="vertical-title" class="col-left">
            <img src="http://www.placehold.it/60x650" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-right">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-half">
                    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/550x325" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-half">
                    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/550x325" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-half">
                    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/550x325" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-half">
                    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/550x325" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
h3 {
    color: blue;
    margin: 5px;
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
}

.img-responsive {
    width: 100%;
}

.col-left {
    max-width: 60px;
    float: left;
}

.col-right {
    max-width: calc(100% - 60px);
    float: left;
}

.col-half {
    width: 49%;
    margin-left: 4px;
    float: left;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .col-half {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: No problem but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need images to be stacked in iPhone? You can add a media query

```
@media only screen 
 and (min-device-width : 568px) { img.img-responsive {
    max-width: 49%;
}}
```

So in iPhone it will stack up and in other it will display the desired effect

Comment: This is still a pending design decision. if I do I was intending on using @media to achieve this behavior. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @iam-decoder for this answer.

All I had to do was change **img.img-responsive** to

```
img.img-responsive  {
  display: inline;
  max-width: 40%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Thanks to all the took time to respond to my question. I am curious however how this is done in JS.